# Am trying to build a class to dynamically update a database but getting this error:

Tags: php, pdo

**

> ( ! ) Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid
>   parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of
>   tokens in

**

Am trying to build a class to dynamically update a database but getting this error: Am struggling to understand because the parameters do actually match. 
Key point: On the localhost - I get the error and the code is not executed but on the live server, the code is executed although, I still get 500 internal server error. Please, what am I getting wrong? or any better idea?

1.THIS IS MY $DATA
   $redirectTo = "https://helpme.com";

```
$data = ['loanamount' => $loanamount,
    'term' => $terms,
    'interest' => $interest,
    'repayment' => $totalrepayment,
    'monthly_repayment=?' => $monthlyrepayment,
    'id' => $id];
```

2.THIS IS MY CLASS

```
  public function updateMultiple($data, $dbtable, $identifier, 
  $identifier_ans, $redirectTo)
  {try{ $implodeKey = implode('=?, ', array_keys($data)); 
  $implodeKey = rtrim($implodeKey, ', id'); 
  $implodeValue = implode(', ', array_values($data)); 
  $sql = "UPDATE $dbtable SET $implodeKey WHERE $identifier =?"; 
  $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql); 
  $result = $stmt->execute([$implodeValue]); 
  if($result){$redirectTo;}} 
  catch (PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;} }
```

I FIXED IT BY USING EXPLODE() TO CONVERT THE $implodeValue back to an ARRAY

```
public function updateMultiple(array $data, $dbtable, $identifier, 
int $identifier_ans)
{$implodeKey = implode('=?, ', array_keys($data)); 
$implodeKey = rtrim($implodeKey, ', id'); 
$implodeValue = array_values($data);
$implodeValue = implode(', ', $implodeValue); 
$implodeValue = explode(" " , $implodeValue);
$sql = "UPDATE $dbtable SET $implodeKey WHERE $identifier =?"; 
$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($implodeValue);
```

3.INSTANTIATE AND IMPLEMENT THE CLASS

```
$insert_db = new Insert();
$insert_db->updateMultiple($data, 'helpme', 'help', $id, $redirectTo);

$sql(var_dump) = 'UPDATE showal_old SET loanamount=?, term=?, interest=?, 
repayment=?, monthly_repayment=? WHERE id =?'

$implodeValue(print_r) `440000, 1, 44000, 484000, 484000, 13964`
```

4. THEN I GET THIS ERROR
   ( ! ) Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs--- $result = $stmt->execute([$implodeValue]); (that is the error line)

Comment: `monthly_repayment=?` can't be a placeholder.

Comment: Any idea on how I can rewrite it?

Comment: I think just `monthly_repayment` should work. I'm assuming that start, length, implode, chunk works. I usually just use `str_repeat`.

Comment: Everything else works. 
this is the var_dump of the $implodeKey 
'loanamount=?, term=?, interest=?, repayment=?, monthly_repayment'

and my problem is how to get a placeholder to the last key in the array (monthly_repayment)

Comment: Don't `- 1;` and use `rtrim` to remove the last `, `. e.g. `$length = $count_array;`  and `$implodeKey = rtrim(implode('=?, ', array_keys($slide_data)), ', ');`

Comment: I wrote the code again using rtrim() but still getting the problem on local server:       public function updateMultiple($data, $dbtable, $identifier, $identifier_ans, $redirectTo){try{
$implodeKey = implode('=?, ', array_keys($data));
$implodeKey = rtrim($implodeKey, ', id'); 
$implodeValue = implode(', ', array_values($data));
$sql = "UPDATE $dbtable SET $implodeKey WHERE $identifier =?";
$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$implodeValue]);
if($result){$redirectTo;}} catch (PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;}
}

Comment: Are you binding `$identifier`s value, or rather the value for that column? Please use the `edit` feature of the question, hard to read code in the comments.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54989363/edit Please add the output of `$sql` and `print_r($implodeValue)` to the question.

Comment: Thank you! solution found by using explode() on $implodeValue before passing it to execute()